# How to remove the "white color" that has Highlighting on the background

Tags: colors, background, settings, visual-studio-2022, background-color

I don't remember what i did on my visual studio 2022. Can someone knows on how to remove or disable it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyB9Z.png)

I was tried to RESET on the option section and set it into default. but nothing has change. The white color in the background in still there.